# AWS Lambda integration with SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

Does AWS lambda provide support for listening to SQS queue? I found some examples which says one can do that but I am not sure if AWS lambda explicity provide support for that. When I create the lambda function, then I found one blueprint for SQS. So,

Answer (score 3):

I linked to it in your other thread - [these are the supported event sources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html).  Notice that [cloudwatch events](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-cloudwatch-events) are one of the possible event types.  You could set up a Lambda to, for example, run every minute and poll an SQS queue.  You cannot directly trigger a Lambda off of an SQS queue.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah one way is polling. What do you mean by Cloudwatch events. Do you mean that from my SQS, I send events to Cloudwatch on which I can have the trigger in Lambda?

Comment: No, from Cloudwatch you send an event to Lambda and it reads the SQS queue.

Comment: Yes, because the only way you can get messages from SQS is to poll.  You cannot be notified of new messages without polling.  SNS is an event driven model.

Comment: Couldn't you have SQS trigger a CloudWatch event when the approximate number of messages was above 1, then have your Lambda function subscribe to that event?

Comment: @idbehold - that would work but now you'll run the Lambda on almost every message and not take advantage of the ability of the Lambda to drain or remove a good number of messages.  You'll end up running the Lambda much more than needed.

Answer (score 3):

Good news, this feature was released yesterday!

> 28 JUN 2018: AWS Lambda Adds Amazon Simple Queue Service to Supported Event Sources

Read the announcement blog post here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/

[AWS Serverless Model](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#sqs) supports a new event source as following:

```
Type: SQS
 PropertiesProperties:
  QueueQueue: arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:012345678901:my-queue arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:0123456789 # NOTE: FIFO SQS Queues are not yet supported
  BatchSize: 10
```

And this is how it can be configured from the AWS Console UI:

[image: lambda sqs event source]

Answer (score 1):

You can make your lambda function poll the queue using the SQS API. You could use SNS to trigger the Lambda function.

Comment: Are you telling 2 ways to do that? One is using SQS and one is using SNS but not SQS, right?

Comment: No you'll need to configure them all to work together as part of the solution.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** AWS Lambda can now be triggered from Amazon SQS queues.

---

**Old answer:**

Rather than having AWS Lambda poll an Amazon SQS queue, the application that sends the message to SQS queue should instead directly invoke the Lambda function. This could be done in several ways:

- Direct invocation via an AWS API call
- Sending a message to an Amazon SNS topic, with the Lambda function subscribed to the topic
- Calling a function via AWS API Gateway, which can then trigger a Lambda function

The extra step of putting a message into an SQS queue is not necessary.

Comment: """The extra step of putting a message into an SQS queue is not necessary."""

Just curious, because of the Lambda concurrency doesn't it make sense to tie Lambda invocation with SQS. I have seen a few AWS articles around the same.

Comment: My response was written before Lambda could trigger from SQS. Lambda concurrency includes waiting in case the concurrency limit has been hit, so you do not need to use SQS. See: [Managing concurrency for a Lambda function - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) and [AWS Lambda function scaling - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-scaling.html).

Comment: Cool - Thanks John - I was looking for something around Lambda and came across this - may be if you get a chance please modify the response.